# How do I access child objects in an eloquent collection?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, collections, one-to-many

I’m new to Laravel and working on creating an API resource to return sales orders.

My controller used three models:

- SalesOrderHeader - list of sales orders
- Salesorderlines - list of items ordered (this could be one or many)
- Item - product details (one to one, joined to salesorderlines)

Below is a code snippet of what I have created so far:

```
    $salesorders = SalesOrderHeader::query()
        ->with('salesorderlines', 'salesorderlines.item')
        ->get();
    
    foreach($salesorders as $order){
    
        //dd($salesorders->toArray());
    
        foreach($order->salesorderline as $line){
    
            dd($line);
    
        }
    }

return OrderResource::collection($salesorders);
```

If I dump the order variable to an array, I can see a child array called “salesorderlines”  which contains sales line and product data.

When I try to dump the individual line elements, I get the following error on the second foreach line:

foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

I would like to add some elements to the salesorderlines collections. I have done this before however this is different as I am not using a single model this time. Would someone be able point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... why are you trying to access `salesorderline` if you say you see an array named `salesorderlines` (plural) ? your relationship is named `salesorderlines` not `salesorderline`, so the dynamic property is `salesorderlines` not `salesorderline` ... if you try to access an attribute or relationship that doesn't exist you get a `null`

Comment: Great thanks that has worked. I misunderstood how it worked and I was using the attribute name rather than the relationship name. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use belongsToMany or belongsTo (inverse) relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

If you want to add some elements use $appends property in your model: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).